# Bug in the EngFormatter when using TeX

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot currents. I want to format the y-axis using the EngFormatter.

```
yformatter = mtick.EngFormatter(unit="A")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yformatter)
```

When currents are in the micro ampere range and the EngFormatter would have to plot a µ, it gives an error if I use tex.

`mpl.rc("text", usetex=True)`

This is the relevant traceback:

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    600         else:
    601             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
--> 602             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    603             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
    604                 page = next(iter(dvi))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    383 
    384         if DEBUG or not os.path.exists(dvifile):
--> 385             texfile = self.make_tex(tex, fontsize)
    386             command = [str("latex"), "-interaction=nonstopmode",
    387                        os.path.basename(texfile)]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in make_tex(self, tex, fontsize)
    298             else:
    299                 try:
--> 300                     fh.write(s.encode('ascii'))
    301                 except UnicodeEncodeError as err:
    302                     mpl.verbose.report("You are using unicode and latex, but "

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u03bc' in position 234: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a workaround for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the full snippet from `texmanager.py`, you find this:

```
if rcParams['text.latex.unicode']:
    fh.write(s.encode('utf8'))
else:
    try:
        fh.write(s.encode('ascii'))
    except UnicodeEncodeError as err:
        _log.info("You are using unicode and latex, but have not "
                  "enabled the 'text.latex.unicode' rcParam.")
        raise
```

You should see them same logged by your program.
If you read [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#usetex-with-unicode), it tells you the same solution: Enable `text.latex.unicode`.

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True
```